# How to use word boundaries in awk without using match() function?

Tags: regex, awk, word-boundary

I want to add word boundaries to this awk command:

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0)};/wordA/&&/wordB/ { print FILENAME ":" $0; }' myfile.txt
```

I tried adding `\y` at left and right of `wordA` and `wordB` but it didn't work in my tests.
I tried this: `/\ywordA\y/&&/\ywordB\y/`

Thanks all!

(ps: I'm new to awk so I was trying to avoid the match() function.)

Comment: Your curly-brackets don't seem to be balanced properly; you have more `}`s than `{`s.

Comment: I only know one version of awk that understands `\b` word boundaries: the one you get when you run it through a2p. :)

Comment: I also tried \b and \<wordA\> but not working (mac osx).

Comment: @fooledbyprimes You don’t understand.  `a2p someawkcode | perl` is the awk-to-perl translator. That way you can get real perl regexes.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use gawk instead of awk:

```
gawk '{$0=tolower($0)};/\ywordA\y/&&/\ywordB\y/ { print FILENAME ":" $0; }' myfile.txt
```

will do what you want, if your system has gawk (e.g. on Mac OS X).  \y is a GNU extension to awk.

Answer (score 2):

1. GNU awk also supports the `\<` and `\>` conventions for word boundaries.
2. On a Mac, /usr/bin/awk version 20070501 does not support [[:<:]] or [[:>:]]
3. If you're stuck with a recalcitrant awk, then since awk is normally splitting lines into tokens anyway, it might make sense to use:

   `function word(s,  i) {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ "^" s "$") {return i}};
    return 0;
   }`

So, for example, instead of writing

```
/\<[abc]\>/ { print "matched"; }
```

you could just as easily write:

```
word("[abc]") { print "matched"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you on [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format):

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0)};/[[:<:]]wordA[[:>:]]/&&/[[:<:]]wordB[[:>:]]/ { print FILENAME ":" $0; }' myfile.txt
```

But as it won't work on linux you're best off installing GNU awk.

Comment: As of MacOS Mojave, this doesn't work for me. `(^|[^A-Za-z0-9_])` works for a starting word boundary and `([^A-Za-z0-9_]|$)` for an ending one (maybe exclude the underscore or perform other tweaks depending on your use case). I don't think this is portable between Awks, either, unfortunately.