# Searching for a value in a file with two delimiters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a datafile in the following format

```
1|col2|col3|105,230,3,44,59,62|col5
2|col2|col3|43,44|col5
3|col2|col3|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8|col5
4|col2|col3|1,2,37|col5
```

- Delimiter is "|"
- 4th column is a comma separated set of numbers.
- I need records that have the number "3" individually in their 4th column but numbers such as 43 or 33 shouldn't count.
- "3" could be at the start of 4th column, in the middle of 4th column or at the end of 4th column

So, desirable records from above given data are

```
1|col2|col3|105,230,3,44,59,62|col5
3|col2|col3|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8|col5
```

I'm currently using the following command but I'm looking for a more efficient/organized one

```
awk -F"|" '$4 ~ /,3,/ || $4 ~ /^3,/ || $4 ~ /,3$/'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F'|' '$4 ~ /\<3\>/' file
```

- `\<` and `\>` - stand for the *start* and *end* of the *word* respectively

The output:

```
1|col2|col3|105,230,3,44,59,62|col5
3|col2|col3|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8|col5
```

---

Or a more unified/portable one:

```
awk -F'|' '$4 ~ /(^|,)3(,|$)/' file
```

Comment: Thanks! This Helps.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to have any values in 4th column which has `3` in it then print the line, if yes then following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk -F"|" '{num=split($4, array,",");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){if(array[i]==3){print;next}}}'   Input_file
```

Comment: @Inian, thank you sir, I changed it now, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are checking the index value to be `3` and _not_ the value from the array `array` which you `split()` on `$4`

Comment: @Inian, I need a cup of coffee, thank you for correcting me here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  I edited the question a little to remove any ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

There is an idiomatic way to deal with splitting fields into sub-fields with GNU awk (although it is overkill in this context). The basic process is this:

1. Save the current record `rec = $0`
2. Save the current field separator `oFS = FS`
3. Choose a new field separator `FS=","`
4. Set `$0` to the field you are interested in `$0 = $4`
5. You can now address the sub-fields with dollar notation etc.
6. Restore the original field separator `FS = oFS`

For example:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN { FS = "|" }

{ rec = $0 }

{ 
  oFS = FS
  FS  = ","
  $0  = $4
}

/\<3\>/ { 
  print rec
}

{ FS = oFS }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
1|col2|col3|105,230,3,44,59,62|col5
3|col2|col3|1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8|col5
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting just the first line as output 

Comment: I suspect that first `FS = oFS` is intended to be `oFS = FS` but this approach is really vast overkill for this problem as well as being inefficient and non-portable. Why go to all the trouble of converting $0 to the $4 value and then testing $0 before printing the original $0 that you had saved in a variable instead of simply [testing $4 and printing $0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883454/1745001)?

Comment: @EdMorton: Editing error fixed, thanks. Overkill, yes, but a flexible way of working when you have more complex problems

Comment: @EdMorton: The non-portable bit seems to be the word-boundary matching?

Comment: Right. That's gawk-only.

Comment: @EdMorton: Interesting, so it is non-portable, noted that in the answer. Some workarounds for word-boundary mathing are provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751652/1331399). I noticed another issue though: the re-splitting and implicit setting of various variables does not work with nawk